# In Kotlin language what is the difference between an internal member and a public member within an internal class?

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
internal class Point {
    internal val x = 0
    public val y = 0
}
```

Since `Point` class is internal, it is only accessible from within the same module. Wouldn't that make both `x` and `y` also accessible only from within the same module? If so, what is the difference between using `internal` and `public` inside an `internal` class?

Comment: No difference..

Comment: You could maybe argue there's a difference in intent there, that `x` is a property that *should* be kept `internal`. Whereas `y` can be public, it's fine, and if `Point` is ever made public then `y` should be part of its visible interface, whereas `x` should always remain internal to the module. The fact someone's bothered to add those modifiers explicitly implies their visibility has been considered separate to the visibility of the class, and changing the *class's* visibility shouldn't automatically mean those properties change with it. Maybe it's enough to get someone to ask questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a distinction without a difference. The difference is that the public property `y` will be gettable publicly, while `x` will not be. In terms of equivalent java, `y` would have a public getter method. But since the class itself is `internal` there is no value to y's getter, at least in a pure Kotlin environment.